# Handling ViewModel Property Changed in Xamarin Forms Content Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I would like to react to a Property being set in my ViewModel (uses INotifyPropertyChanged) in my Xamarin Forms ContentPage code behind.

Assuming I can access my ViewModel, I "could" do this like so -

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // My base class enabled ViewModel access
        ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.PropertyName + " Changed on ViewModel");

            if (e.PropertyName == "Bob")
            {
                DoSomething();
            }
        };
```

Do I have to think about unregistering from the PropertyChanged event on ViewModel dispose?

Are there any other more elegant ways of doing this?

For example, I have seen mentioned ways of achieving it using Rx Extensions, I have used a MvxPropertyChangedListener with Mvvmcross to help with this kind of thing.

In response to @Jesus Angulo, the reason I am doing this right now is to programatically populate a StackLayout within a scrollview when my List of items change, just so I do not have to set up any custom binding code.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? because it depends.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* have to do this, I would suggest using messaging center to publish a message in the view model which you subscribe to in the page behind.

[Here is a how to on Messaging Center](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/)

But there really must be a way to do all this in the view model.

Can't you change the StackLayout to a ListView and populate a list of things when the property changes?